# mouse hover on anchor tag does not display pointer cursor. Behavior observed on Chrome, works fine on IE 9?

Tags: html, google-chrome, anchor, mouse-cursor

I have a code in my razor view as below. The pointer cursor is not displaying while mouse hover on any of the anchor tag. The same code works fine on IE 9. This issue is observed on Chrome browser.

Any guess why the below code failed on Chrome Version 25.0.1364.172 m?

```
<ul id="menu" class="menu">
   <li><a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Top 10 Headlines</a>
   </li>
    <li><a href="#">Related Content</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 19):

Do you have Developer tools open? For some reason cursor will not show as pointer while this tool is open. Close it and try again.

Comment: Thats bugged me for ages!! Considered it intermittent.

Comment: And everyone keeps telling me Chrome is the best browser. Glad to be a Firefox loyal user :)

Comment: @LetsGoRangers - This just helped me 2,381 days after your original post in April 2013.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is chrome developer tools as stated by LetsGoRangers

Fix:
Press F12 
Click on the gear icon (lower right in version 27)
Click override (left column)
make sure "emulate touch events" is unchecked.

The cursor should appear even with Developer Tools open now.

There have been issues where it will check itself after restarting chrome. You may need to reinstall chrome to fix this.