# Has anyone noticed an issue with links on chrome that prevents the pointer to be shown on hover with inspector activated?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

On Chrome version 26.0.1410.43 m, I was wondering if anyone had noticed the following issue...

The cursor no longer appears on links hover while the chrome-devtools inspector is activated...

Additionally, there is a user agent stylesheet applied to links

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
  color: -webkit-link;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

Is this a duplicate of the following as it is observed on a more recent version of Chrome exclusively as well? [mouse hover on anchor tag does not display pointer cursor. Behavior observed on Chrome, works fine on IE 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730025/mouse-hover-on-anchor-tag-does-not-display-pointer-cursor-behavior-observed-on)

This is also interesting but does not show the cursor change... [How to use chrome web inspector to view hover code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789739/how-to-use-chrome-web-inspector-to-view-hover-code)

Are there any settings to apply to prevent that?

THX

Comment: thx for checking Rob, I'll try and reproduce on another env as well...
cheers!

Comment: You can try a new profile using `chromium --user-data-dir=/tmp/whatever` (or `chrome --user-data-dir=%tmp%\whatever` on Windows)

Comment: thx again Rob, it actually confirmed @superhighfives info and come to think of it, i recently was working on #responsive design and remember having tweaked some settings...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is caused by having [Emulate touch events](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation) selected in your Web Inspector settings. Just untick and you're good to go.

---

[image: Emulate touch events example screengrab]

Comment: wicked, it actually was the culprit! THX superhighfives :)