# div style cursor pointer is not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3

I have added custom controller to google map api.
one div in the custom controller should be clickable.
I have added `cursor:pointer` as the style.
It works well in firefox but not in chrome.
In chrome browser, it displays the hand icon but click action
is not working.

This is the code I added to my html file for add the html to the custom controller.

```
controlText.innerHTML = '<div id="newid" class="myclass" style="width:380px; margin-left:40px; margin-bottom:20px;">Click here to proceed</div></div>';
```

I have added to the click event listner as following.

```
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].clear();
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT].clear();
    var inputfieldControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var inputfieldControl = new TextfieldControl(inputfieldControlDiv, map);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(inputfieldControlDiv);
```

css file

```
.myclass{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: If you can add some code, much helpful.

Comment: Please share your code on JSFIDDLE

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Why didn't you show us your TextfieldControl function? why is it such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Tested it in Mozzila, Opera, IE11, Chrome and it works (it always shows the cursors specified in your class)

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/kphe5fbL/10/

I've included the following code of yours: `controlText.innerHTML = '<div id="newid" class="myclass" style="width:380px; margin-left:40px; margin-bottom:20px;">Click here to proceed</div></div>';` and the clearing as well altought I believe they are not necessary.

Here is the full code JS that is in the fiddle:

```
var map;
var london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);
function TextfieldControl(controlDiv, map) {

    var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
    var controlText = document.createElement('div');
    controlText.innerHTML = '<div id="newid" class="myclass" onclick="alert()"style="width:380px; margin-left:40px; margin-bottom:20px;">Click here to proceed</div></div>';
    controlUI.appendChild(controlText);
}

function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googleMap');
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: london,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);

    var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var homeControl = new TextfieldControl(homeControlDiv, map);

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].clear();  
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT].clear();
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(homeControlDiv);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Of-course, the cursor will switch to value "default" at some point because of your margins css set to some pixels.

**EDIT**

The only other issue that could make the obstruction here is that you have developer tools tab open, this has been solved in this stackoverflow thread:

url: [mouse hover on anchor tag does not display pointer cursor. Behavior observed on Chrome, works fine on IE 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730025/mouse-hover-on-anchor-tag-does-not-display-pointer-cursor-behavior-observed-on)

If you still have problems then you shoul reveal your *TestfieldControl* function.